# google calender api setColorId

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I want to do something `event.setColorId("RED")` to change my event color
unfortunetaly this is the response i got

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
```

does anyone know the correct way?

Thanks

Comment: I created an event in my calendar and look the getEventList response on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list It return "colorId": "11" for red can you try event.setColorId("11") ?

Comment: Event colors value should be the one which are available in the response when you send request to colors(https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get). You should give value as colorId="1" which takes value as below: "11": { "background": "#dc2127", "foreground": "#1d1d1d" }. You can also refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881943/google-calendar-java-set-up-google-event-colour-and-event-date-from-timestamp/31884156?noredirect=1#comment51739649_31884156

Answer (score 0):

You should do `event.setColorId("11")` for red.

These are all the possible options for colorId.

```json
"1": {
   "background": "#ac725e",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "2": {
   "background": "#d06b64",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "3": {
   "background": "#f83a22",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "4": {
   "background": "#fa573c",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "5": {
   "background": "#ff7537",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "6": {
   "background": "#ffad46",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "7": {
   "background": "#42d692",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "8": {
   "background": "#16a765",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "9": {
   "background": "#7bd148",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "10": {
   "background": "#b3dc6c",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "11": {
   "background": "#fbe983",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "12": {
   "background": "#fad165",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "13": {
   "background": "#92e1c0",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "14": {
   "background": "#9fe1e7",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "15": {
   "background": "#9fc6e7",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "16": {
   "background": "#4986e7",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "17": {
   "background": "#9a9cff",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "18": {
   "background": "#b99aff",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "19": {
   "background": "#c2c2c2",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "20": {
   "background": "#cabdbf",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "21": {
   "background": "#cca6ac",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "22": {
   "background": "#f691b2",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "23": {
   "background": "#cd74e6",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "24": {
   "background": "#a47ae2",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  }
 },
 "event": {
  "1": {
   "background": "#a4bdfc",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "2": {
   "background": "#7ae7bf",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "3": {
   "background": "#dbadff",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "4": {
   "background": "#ff887c",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "5": {
   "background": "#fbd75b",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "6": {
   "background": "#ffb878",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "7": {
   "background": "#46d6db",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "8": {
   "background": "#e1e1e1",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "9": {
   "background": "#5484ed",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "10": {
   "background": "#51b749",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "11": {
   "background": "#dc2127",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  }
```